# ios animating bar above keyboard

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, keyboard

I want to animate a bar above my keyboard when the keyboard pops up. I want to do this by first hiding my bar at the very bottom of my screen, animating the bar up the height of the bar at the same rate as the keyboard animation, and then have both the keyboard and bar animate at the same time, with the bar hugging the keyboard.

The issue is timing the start of the keyboard animation. On first time load, the keyboard takes a bit of time, so the bar animates first, but there's a slight pause until the keyboard starts animating. I'd like this transition to be smooth.

Is there an easier way to think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a view just above the keyboard, when keyboard appears and hide it when keyboard hides, you can do this by setting inputAccessoryView property of UITextField Or UITextView which shows the view as AccessoryView of keyboard when it appears on that particular UITextField or UITextView.

In my example i wanted a UIToolBar With a done button on my keyboard when it appears on UITextView so once user complete writing the contents he/she can hide keyboard by clicking on that UIToolBarButtonItem. The code is as below:

```
[txtViewDescription setInputAccessoryView:toolBarAccesoryView];
```

In the above code txtViewDescription is a UITextView and toolBarAccesoryView is a UIToolbar which can be any UIView object you want.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to do some additional setup to make the tool bar visible. As I have set input accessoryview but its not showing. I am using decimal pad not full qwerty keyboard.

Comment: Yes you need to create UIToolbar object.
OR You can bind one with outlet, then use that object in the setInputAccessoryView.

In such scenario while using outlet of toolbar, first design it within your view and then drag it outside the Yellow icon that is your view controller from left pane. Doing this will hide the toolbar from your view and will be accessed & displayed by the setInputAccessoryView Method when required.

You can see the same scenario as i have mentioned in the image above.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the UIKeyboardNotifications provided by Apple. I would recommend the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`.

I imagine if you have implemented the animation in some form you are already using some or all of these notifications.

You should be using this for the obvious reasons of have the correct frames during the animation:

```
NSString *const UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey;
NSString *const UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey;
```

These two notifications will provide the CGRect for the start and end frame of the keyboard respectively.

It sounds like what you want though are these two notifications:

```
NSString *const UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey;
NSString *const UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey;
```

The first of these will give you the duration of the animation, which is obviously what you are looking for. The second will give you the animation curve used by the keyboard, which could also be quite helpful in keep consistent with the animation as a whole.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: James, I marked the harish's answer as the right answer. All you do is set the inputAccessoryView of your textview or textfield and it takes care of everything for you. I ran a few tests on the startframe of the keyboard and found that after converting from window coordinates to my main view, the origin didn't change. Regardless, inputAccessoryView is the way to go.